# Requesting input from the user in Octave

Tags: input, octave

I need to get input for my program in Octave from the user. When I include the input command and continue writing the script, after running the script, the lines following the input command in the script are taken as the input. Is it possible for the script to wait at the input command till the user gives an input and then continue with the script?

For e.g. consider this part of my script:

```
n=input('Give the number of nodes')
names=char('Paul', 'Jane', 'Sam', 'Chris')
```

When I execute these statements, this is what the command window shows:

```
>> n=input('Give the number of nodes')

Give the number of nodesnames=char('Paul', 'Jane', 'Sam', 'Chris')

n =

Paul
Jane
Sam
Chris
```

Comment: What are the output of `computer ()` and `version` ?

Comment: Please add operating system and version. Are you executing your code in a script or pasting the code to a command window?

Comment: @Andy Windows OS, Octave version 4.0.2. I am not pasting the code to a command window. I write the code in the editor and run it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code

```
n=input('Give the number of nodes')
names=char('Paul', 'Jane', 'Sam', 'Chris')
```

put in a `try_input.m` file, does work.

```
>> version
ans = 4.0.1
```

Good also with versions `4.0.0` and `3.8.2`.

This is under linux.

Comment: No, it doesn't. My version is 4.0.2. Windows 10. You got what the problem is, right? The executor does not wait for the user to give the input. After reading the input line, it goes straight to the next line, takes that as the input and stores those names in n.

Comment: @swatipratyusha Yes, I did understand what the problem was. The script is interpreted as if characters where typed (like upon copy/paste). The point of my answer was versions and operating system. So there might be a bug on windows. Time to [file a bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave), with a link to this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a semicolon works fine in the command prompt of a 3.8.1 version under Linux (but it won't without it).

```
n=input('Give the number of nodes'); names=char('Paul', 'Jane', 'Sam', 'Chris')
```